# How to achieve text shadow like this?

Tags: css, box-shadow

I wanted to get a shadow under a text as in attached pic. In attached we can see a shadow under a text "website". I tried using below code but unsuccessful. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```css
#testbtn {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #0098DB;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  background: #575857;
  max-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.trying {
  color: white;
  content: "";
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
  text-transform: rotateX(70deg);
}
```

```html
<a id="testbtn"><span class="trying">Test</span></a>
```

Comment: Where did you see this effect? Please update your question with the link since you might be able to inspect the element to see what styles are on it.

Comment: Do you want that exact effect or just extended text shadow?

Comment: If possible exact effect would be great for my project!

Comment: I added an answer below and made an edit showing a snippet for drawing a parallelogram. You should have all the pieces here to get you going...a few strategies to approach this...maybe best is drawing a parallelogram to your desired color and then positioning it beneath and at the bottom of your text (while also adding a thin `text-shadow` to the nav text itself).

Comment: I am confused here, do I hve to construct a parallelogram to show a shadow effect on text. any example will be great!

Comment: @david, I will try and mock one up for you using your snippet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @natureminded. I don't think text-transform would be best to achieve this result. I was drafting up this example after they posted their answer, but it follows the same thought process

```css
#testbtn {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #0098DB;
  padding: 8px 8px; 
  background:#575857;
  max-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: -3;
}

.trying{
  position: relative;
  color:white;
} 

.trying:before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 6px;
  top: 7px;
  height: 110%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0, .5);
  transform: skew(35deg);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<a id="testbtn"><span class="trying">Test</span></a>
```

Comment: Hey you got it! +1. I guess my text-shadow approach was not the best.

Comment: @Joe B. This snippet looks great. david there you go, you got a mockup. There are obviously a few different ways these things can be approached, and the choice is yours!

Comment: @JoeB do you think a text-shadow approach could also look like this?

Comment: @david Fiddling around some more, you can also add a `box-shadow` to the `.trying:before` and adjust opacity levels to give it a softer look.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the `text-shadow` CSS attribute and using CSS to draw a parellelogram.

The syntax is as follows:

```
text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color|none|initial|inherit;
```

You can checkout the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp) link about it for more information.

In the most basic sense, you could apply a shadow to the `.trying` class directly:

`text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000000;`

This will get a shadow going on the text itself, but, I do not believe the `text-shadow` property is capable of doing what you wish, in regards to the shadow in your attached JPG. (You will need to draw a shape or use sprites).

As another commenter noted, can you provide the original page in which you saw the image, so one could analyze how they achieved the result?

The box-shadow you are applying will not add a shadow to the text directly, but instead to the element border itself (thus why the shadow is on the outliers of the `Test` text).

Here's some more information also from w3schools, on [sprites](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_sprites.asp), if you chose to pursue that route -- which is another way you could do it, but probably best to just use shape drawing and text-shadow via CSS.

**EDIT FOR DRAWING SHAPES:**

Here's a code to draw a parallelogram -- you could modify this to achieve your effect possibly:

```
#parallelogram {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    background: red;
}
```

Courtesy of CSS tricks, here's the full link on [drawing shapes](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) with CSS. If you created a second element, and used relative/absolute positioning and a z-index, you could place it beneath your nav text. Just modify the color, maybe give it some opacity (modify the snippet above) and you should be on your way...

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly the same but it's close.

```css
body {
  background-color: #9FCDE8;
}

.shadow1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30pt;
  text-shadow:
   1px  1px  5px #7FA4B8,
   2px  2px  5px #7FA4B8,
   3px  3px  5px #7FA4B8,
   4px  4px  5px #7FA4B8,
   5px  5px  5px #7FA4B8,
   6px  6px  5px #7FA4B8,
   7px  7px  5px #7FA4B8,
   8px  8px  5px #7FA4B8,
   9px  9px  5px #7FA4B8,
  10px 10px  5px #7FA4B8,
  11px 11px  5px #7FA4B8,
  12px 12px  5px #7FA4B8,
  13px 13px  5px #7FA4B8,
  14px 14px  5px #7FA4B8,
  15px 15px  5px #7FA4B8,
  16px 16px  5px #7FA4B8,
  17px 17px  5px #7FA4B8,
  18px 18px  5px #7FA4B8,
  19px 19px  5px #7FA4B8,
  20px 20px  5px #7FA4B8,
  21px 21px  5px #7FA4B8,
  22px 22px  5px #7FA4B8,
  23px 23px  5px #7FA4B8,
  24px 24px  5px #7FA4B8,
  25px 25px  5px #7FA4B8,
  26px 26px  5px #7FA4B8,
  27px 27px  5px #7FA4B8,
  28px 28px  5px #7FA4B8,
  29px 29px  5px #7FA4B8,
  30px 30px  5px #7FA4B8,
  31px 31px  5px #7FA4B8,
  32px 32px  5px #7FA4B8,
  33px 33px  5px #7FA4B8,
  34px 34px  5px #7FA4B8,
  35px 35px  5px #7FA4B8,
  36px 36px  5px #7FA4B8,
  37px 37px  5px #7FA4B8,
  38px 38px  5px #7FA4B8,
  39px 39px  5px #7FA4B8,
  40px 40px  5px #7FA4B8,
  41px 41px  5px #7FA4B8,
  42px 42px  5px #7FA4B8,
  43px 43px  5px #7FA4B8,
  44px 44px  5px #7FA4B8,
  45px 45px  5px #7FA4B8,
  46px 46px  5px #7FA4B8,
  47px 47px  5px #7FA4B8,
  48px 48px  5px #7FA4B8,
  49px 49px  5px #7FA4B8,
  50px 50px  5px #7FA4B8;
}

.shadow2 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30pt;
  text-shadow:
   1px  1px 10px #7FA4B8,
   2px  2px 10px #7FA4B8,
   3px  3px 10px #7FA4B8,
   4px  4px 10px #7FA4B8,
   5px  5px 10px #7FA4B8,
   6px  6px 10px #7FA4B8,
   7px  7px 10px #7FA4B8,
   8px  8px 10px #7FA4B8,
   9px  9px 10px #7FA4B8,
  10px 10px 10px #7FA4B8,
  11px 11px 10px #7FA4B8,
  12px 12px 10px #7FA4B8,
  13px 13px 10px #7FA4B8,
  14px 14px 10px #7FA4B8,
  15px 15px 10px #7FA4B8,
  16px 16px 10px #7FA4B8,
  17px 17px 10px #7FA4B8,
  18px 18px 10px #7FA4B8,
  19px 19px 10px #7FA4B8,
  20px 20px 10px #7FA4B8,
  21px 21px 10px #7FA4B8,
  22px 22px 10px #7FA4B8,
  23px 23px 10px #7FA4B8,
  24px 24px 10px #7FA4B8,
  25px 25px 10px #7FA4B8,
  26px 26px 10px #7FA4B8,
  27px 27px 10px #7FA4B8,
  28px 28px 10px #7FA4B8,
  29px 29px 10px #7FA4B8,
  30px 30px 10px #7FA4B8,
  31px 31px 10px #7FA4B8,
  32px 32px 10px #7FA4B8,
  33px 33px 10px #7FA4B8,
  34px 34px 10px #7FA4B8,
  35px 35px 10px #7FA4B8,
  36px 36px 10px #7FA4B8,
  37px 37px 10px #7FA4B8,
  38px 38px 10px #7FA4B8,
  39px 39px 10px #7FA4B8,
  40px 40px 10px #7FA4B8,
  41px 41px 10px #7FA4B8,
  42px 42px 10px #7FA4B8,
  43px 43px 10px #7FA4B8,
  44px 44px 10px #7FA4B8,
  45px 45px 10px #7FA4B8,
  46px 46px 10px #7FA4B8,
  47px 47px 10px #7FA4B8,
  48px 48px 10px #7FA4B8,
  49px 49px 10px #7FA4B8,
  50px 50px 10px #7FA4B8;
}

.shadow3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30pt;
  text-shadow:
   1px  1px 15px #7FA4B8,
   2px  2px 15px #7FA4B8,
   3px  3px 15px #7FA4B8,
   4px  4px 15px #7FA4B8,
   5px  5px 15px #7FA4B8,
   6px  6px 15px #7FA4B8,
   7px  7px 15px #7FA4B8,
   8px  8px 15px #7FA4B8,
   9px  9px 15px #7FA4B8,
  10px 10px 15px #7FA4B8,
  11px 11px 15px #7FA4B8,
  12px 12px 15px #7FA4B8,
  13px 13px 15px #7FA4B8,
  14px 14px 15px #7FA4B8,
  15px 15px 15px #7FA4B8,
  16px 16px 15px #7FA4B8,
  17px 17px 15px #7FA4B8,
  18px 18px 15px #7FA4B8,
  19px 19px 15px #7FA4B8,
  20px 20px 15px #7FA4B8,
  21px 21px 15px #7FA4B8,
  22px 22px 15px #7FA4B8,
  23px 23px 15px #7FA4B8,
  24px 24px 15px #7FA4B8,
  25px 25px 15px #7FA4B8,
  26px 26px 15px #7FA4B8,
  27px 27px 15px #7FA4B8,
  28px 28px 15px #7FA4B8,
  29px 29px 15px #7FA4B8,
  30px 30px 15px #7FA4B8,
  31px 31px 15px #7FA4B8,
  32px 32px 15px #7FA4B8,
  33px 33px 15px #7FA4B8,
  34px 34px 15px #7FA4B8,
  35px 35px 15px #7FA4B8,
  36px 36px 15px #7FA4B8,
  37px 37px 15px #7FA4B8,
  38px 38px 15px #7FA4B8,
  39px 39px 15px #7FA4B8,
  40px 40px 15px #7FA4B8,
  41px 41px 15px #7FA4B8,
  42px 42px 15px #7FA4B8,
  43px 43px 15px #7FA4B8,
  44px 44px 15px #7FA4B8,
  45px 45px 15px #7FA4B8,
  46px 46px 15px #7FA4B8,
  47px 47px 15px #7FA4B8,
  48px 48px 15px #7FA4B8,
  49px 49px 15px #7FA4B8,
  50px 50px 15px #7FA4B8;
}
```

```html
<span class="shadow1">a website</span>
<span class="shadow2">a website</span>
<span class="shadow3">a website</span>
```

Comment: Ricky Joe B provided excellent answer, please update your answer too: I will like to see different approached for solving my question!

Comment: This is another great option. Would love to see the final edit, to see what the right "recipe" is.

Comment: Oh believe me, I've tried many many many recipes. I could open a bake shop and write a cooking book!! Still trying here ^.^

Comment: Tell me what you think! @david

Comment: Tell me what you think!  @JoeB.

Comment: What if you add another box-shadow? :P  Impressive! I think number 3 is closest to the example image. But I think it also confirms that text-shadow might not be the best approach.

Comment: @JoeB. You mean another text-shadow? It doesn't work and just ends up overwriting the previous one :( just like if you used `color: blue` and then `color: red`, the text will never be blue.

Comment: Doh! yeah I mean `text-shadow`. I guess my humor didn't come across very well... I was trying to imply that you hadn't added enough values. :)